# Separate channels with pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio, jitsi

I have a java voip aplication, jitsi,  that uses pulseaudio for sound.
Id like to run two instances of them at the same time, and make the sound from one go to the right channel, and from the other one go to the right channel.

When only one instance is running, the sound should go normally to both channels.

Can i do this by command line in real time with pacmd ?

Thankyou so much for your help.

CC